# python scipy.interpolate.griddata only performs well in method='nearest'

Tags: python, interpolation, data-fitting

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry I couldnt figure out how to insert figures in the text, so they are above. They will be described below.
I'm fitting toy experimental data to simulated data. At the moment the toy data is interpolated from the simulations and added with an artificial uncertainty.
To fit, I need to feed the minimization algorithm with a function body, where I insert the interpolation via scipy.interpolate.griddata: 
`griddata(sim_params, sim_matrix[:,2], (f, t), method='...')`
If I choose method='nearest', the interpolation works quite well, but to "return the value at the data point closest to the point of interpolation" isn't really what I want. I need better interpolation. However if I use the other two methods, the interpolation is completely off, and I have no idea how to resolve this.
The simulated data is a variable in dependency of a variable on a logarithmic scale and on another variable on a linear scale. In the plots above, latter variable is on the x-axis. The other one is being fitted. Note, that there is plenty of simulated data outside of the used interval. 
Second img is for method='linear', third for method='cubic'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by utilizing the rescale option of griddata:

`griddata(sim_params, sim_matrix[:,2], (f, t), method='linear', rescale=True)`